# What is the best way to use dist and public folders in a webpack app

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, structure

I am trying to do a webpack project but every tutorial I see on the internet uses the same **folder for assets and distribuition**, but I would like to know if there's a better way to manage assets and static files in a folder and than build everything in a Dist or Build folder later.

The structure would be:

```
| /src -> every coding including css and other html pages.

| /public -> index.html, favicon.ico...

        | /public/assets -> put images and other stuff here
```

and later:

```
| /dist -> combine everything in here: index.html, js files and assets.
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be the point of [file-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Add this rule to `webpack.config.js`

```json
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
      outputPath: 'assets',
      publicPath: 'assets',
  },
}
```

In webpack5, the rule can be this one, click [asset-modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) for more details

```
{
  type: 'asset/resource',
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
  generator: {
    filename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]'
  },
}
```

Comment: Isn't file-loader deprecated on webpack 5?